# Can you Package a Database Server & Client in a Native Application?

Tags: database, http, architecture, installation, localhost

I know this question is vague, and that I am asking it poorly, but I still want to ask. I've focused in web development, specifically with Node.js, and I am self-taught, so my knowledge can be spotty.

In the case of a website, if you need a database, then you manually set it up on a local port, or use a cloud provider option like AWS, then use a client to communicate with it.

**But in the case of native application development, how do you replicate that locally?**

I've developed with databases running on local ports before, but I am not sure how to replicate that for an application a user would install. My best answer is to use options like sqlite that don't require a port and just saves to a local `.sqlite` file.

But what if I want to integrate with services that communicate on ports? I know how to install services and develop with them locally on my own machine, but not how you would do so on a client's. Maybe use an install wizard or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is platform-dependent.  Deploying on windows you would create an installation package with [Windows Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/windows-installer-portal) (or alternative) scripts that would install the software to run on those ports (including service installation & such).  On Linux you would similarly use your package manager or install script.

Alternatively you can embed it into the executable itself, many database engines have embedded versions that still open an external port.  You would just need user permission if you needed to modify firewall rules to allow external port access.